# Why does JSON.parse("foo") fail but JSON.parse(' "foo" ') success?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

When I try to `JSON.parse("foo")`, I get an Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

But, when I use `JSON.parse('"foo"')`, I can get the result as expected:

```js
const value = JSON.parse('"foo"');
console.log(value)
```

So why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find what makes valid JSON at [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). JSON can represent null, booleans, numbers, strings, arrays and objects. For strings, they must be enclosed in double quotes.

JSON itself is a string format, so when you specify a string in JSON format, you need:

1. quotes to tell JavaScript you are specifying a string literal. Those quotes are not part of the string value itself; they are just delimiters.
2. double-quotes inside that string literal to follow the JSON syntax for the string data type.

So here are some examples of correct arguments for `JSON.parse`:

- `JSON.parse("true")`
- `JSON.parse("false")`
- `JSON.parse("null")`
- `JSON.parse("42")`
- `JSON.parse("[13]")`
- `JSON.parse('"hello"')`
- `JSON.parse('{"name": "Mary"}')`

But not:

- `JSON.parse("yes")`
- `JSON.parse("no")`
- `JSON.parse("none")`
- `JSON.parse('hello')`
- `JSON.parse({"name": "Mary"})`

Because the argument will be cast to string when it is not, the following will also work, but it is confusing (and useless):

- `JSON.parse(true)`
- `JSON.parse(false)`
- `JSON.parse(null)`
- `JSON.parse(42)`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `JSON.parse()` gives a value back by formatting the string given using the [syntaxis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) to declare values in Javascript. Therefore using `foo` naked would be like casting an undefined variable.

Notice also that the notation uses double quotes `"` instead of single ones `'`. That's why `JSON.parse('"foo"')` works but `JSON.parse("'foo'")` won't.